# Virtualbox >= 6.0.2: Unity crashes on startup

Tags: 16.04, unity, virtualbox, compiz, crash

I am using a barebones Ubuntu 16.04 in VirtualBox, macOS host.  Up to VirtualBox 6.0.0, everything was working fine. But with VirtualBox 6.0.2, 6.0.4 and 6.0.6, Unity crashes on startup. In `~/.xession-errors` I see lines similar to

```
upstart: unity7 main process (3256) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (3290) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (3324) killed by SEGV signal
upstart: unity7 main process ended, respawning
upstart: unity7 main process (3358) killed by SEGV signal
```

Is anyone else experiencing this, or is it specific to my setup? Is there any other solution than downgrading to VirtualBox 6.0.0?

Turning off 3D acceleration in VirtualBox fixes the problem, but also makes Ubuntu unusably slow.

Answer (score 2):

This bug report should enlighten you. There's a bugfix available via guest additions beta version:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18325

If the direct link to the beta ISO mentioned there does not work - there's a link on "test builds", just look there for the latest version:
https://virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

**UPDATE**: As the - currently - only working TestBuild was removed I uploaded the working Guest Additions to the following link (available until 04/2020):
https://file.town/download/fj25drxul6zxnl88pz398pmwt

Background: It seems like the problem (library linking error) regressed in current Guest Addition Releases (at least <= 6.0.6): https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18324

So we're still waiting for the real fix...

**UPDATE 2**: With VirtualBox 6.0.10 released, the problems are gone, as also mentioned within the [ticket description](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18324). Head to the following page to download the latest version and also install latest Guest Additions to Host(s): https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Sadly the guest additions link references there is no longer working, so I can't try it. Hopefully this will be in 6.0.6 (or whichever version is next).

Comment: I downloaded test build 129045 for macOS, and installed the guest additions contained within ("6.0.5"). Unfortunately, the problem is still present in this version.

Comment: I also tried the guest additions test build revision 129041. It also does not work.

Comment: Do you know where one can get a test version that includes this fix? 129665 does not.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Do you really also install the guest additions into the guest machine? It's not enough to just install the guest additions into VirtualBox! I'm asking because obviously every newer GA version is working for some people except for you...?

Comment: Yes, I do install the guest additions into the guest (isn't that the only way to install them)? I downloaded the guest additions test build separately and installed them.

Comment: I wanted to note that 6.0.0 works perfectly.  Of course, I still need to install the 6.0.0 guest additions. VB 6.0.0 with latest test guest additions *does not* work.  I did not try the latest test version of VB with the 6.0.0 guest additions (the reverse) though.

Comment: Are you certain that the version I referenced included the fix?  I assumed that the fix was added as a test, then removed again.  As I said above, the 6.0.0 guest additions work perfectly.  This shows that I am indeed installing guest additions correctly, otherwise installing the 6.0.0 ones would not work.

Comment: 6.0.6 is out and it does _not_ fix this (meanwhile 6.0.0 works perfectly).

Comment: I added the working GA.iso to a temporary download location, should work with this snapshot. I hope this problem gets fixed soon, too..

Comment: I confirm that the version you uploaded works fine. I tried in 6.0.0 and 6.0.6.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround from https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18324 worked for me, after opening up the terminal in a (ctrl+alt+F1) and logging in:

```
sudo apt install patchelf  # For Debian/Ubuntu etc.
sudo patchelf --add-needed libcrypt.so.1 /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-6.0.6/lib/VBoxOGLcrutil.so
```

Comment: This helped me to fix the issue where `lightdm` used to crash on login to Ubuntu Guest OS on MacOS host. I am currently using VirtualBox version 6.0.8 and VirtualBox Guest Additions version 6.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. This one from Development snapshots section worked in my case. https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.97-129282.iso

Comment: I did not have the time to test at that time, and with 129665 it does not work.  129282 is no longer available.